# How to make a setter optional in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

What I have is a class intended to represent a value in the screen:

```js
export class Category() {
  constructor() {}
  private _name?: string;
  private _viewValue?: string;

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
    this._viewValue = getViewValue(name);
  }
  get viewValue() {
    return this._viewValue;
  }
  set viewValue (value: string) {
    this._viewValue = value;
  }
}

function getViewValue(value: string): string {
  switch (value) {
    case 'a1': {
      return 'A1';
    }
    case 'a1': {
        return 'A2';
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to set this values, it requires me to set a value for the viewValue property. What i want to do is to make the `set viewValue(value)` optional, as I was able to do with `_name` and `_value`.

I tried already doing `set? viewValue(value)`, `set viewValue?(value)` and `set viewValue(value)?` but none of those really work.

And I can of course make the viewValue setter just do nothing, but is it really impossible to make a set optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't write setter. But `category.viewValue = ''` will throw error. You can use public property `viewValue` without getter/setter.

There are different kinds of property descriptor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). You can not mix data and accessor descriptors.

```js
export class Category() {
  constructor() {}
  private _name?: string;

  viewValue?: string;

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
    this.viewValue = getViewValue(name);
  }
}
```